# Slick owerflow width going infinite

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I am trying to make my Slick slider . Everything works fine but the width of it goes crazy.
I tried to owerflow it . Basically I owerflowed everything , but no luck .
I can see the actual problem is this slick-track , but no matter what I try, I just cant solve it.
I searched on internet a lot about it but there are no good answers.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<section class="slider-box">
<div class="movie-tape">
  <div class="top-bar bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./images/sonic-slide.jpeg);"><span class="hide">hide</span></div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./images/jumanji-slide.jpg);"><span class="hide">hide</span></div>
    <div class="slide" style="background-image: url(./images/onward-slide.jpg);"><span class="hide">hide</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="botom-bar bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
      <li class="white"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
'use strict'
```

$('document').ready(function(){

```
$('.slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    speed: 2000,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnDotsHover: false


 })


});

.slider-box {

padding: 80px 0;

.movie-tape {
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 120px;

    @include breakpoint (tablet) {
        padding: 0px 40px;
    }

    @include breakpoint (phone) {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

.slider {
    border-left: 20px solid $black;
    border-right: 20px solid $black;
}

.bar {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: $black;
    overflow: hidden;

    li {
        background-color: $white;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;            
    }

    @include breakpoint (phone) {

        height: 20px;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;

        li {
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-left: 14px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
    }
}

.slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 700px;
    background-position: center;
}

button {
    display: none !important;
}

@include breakpoint (tablet) {

    .slide {
        height: 600px;
    }
}

@include breakpoint (phone) {

    .slide {
        height: 280px;
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: it's because all the other slides you can't see are hidden on the side. that's just how it (`.slick-track`) is

Comment: Hmmm, ok sounds resonable ,is there a fix to it >? What could be done ?

Comment: As i understood you want to achieve next or previous slide will be visible..?  then you can use centermode true